# how to solve submit value empty in $_POST Method?

Tags: php, html

1. this is my html form

   ```
   <?php
   session_start ();
   if (! isset ( $_SESSION ['is_logged_in'] )) {
       header ( "Location: login.php" );
   };
   ?>

   <?php 
       include '../functions/process-database.php';

   ?>


   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Cp1252">
   <title>VSN Treks Nepal :: Your Trusted Trekking Partner in Nepal</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <script src="../scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
   <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
   <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.3.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


   <script>
    $(document).ready(

             /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
             function () {
               $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                 changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
                 changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
               });
             }

           );
    </script>

   </head>
   <body>

       <div class="wrapper">

           <div class="header">
       <?php include 'includes/admin-header.php';?>
   </div>
           <!-- header ends -->

           <div class="nav-bar">
               <div class="main-menu">
           <?php include 'includes/admin-nav-bar.php';?>
       </div>
           </div>
           <!-- nab-bar end -->

           <div class="add-activitie-content">
               <h1>Add Activitie</h1>
               <form action="execute/process-add-activitie.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   <p>
                       <label>Title :</label><input type="text" name="title" class="input" required>
                   </p>

                   <p>
                       <label>Description :</label>
                       <textarea name="description" class="add" required></textarea>
                   </p>

                   <p>
                       <label>Date :</label><input type="date" name="date" class="input" id="datepicker" required>
                   </p>

                   <p>
                       <label>Image :</label><input type="file" name="img" class="image" required>
                   </p>

                   <p>
                       <label>Category :</label> <select name="category_id" class="select" required>

                           <?php
                               $query = "SELECT * FROM category";
                               $result = mysqli_query ( $conn, $query );

                           while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {

                               ?>
                           <?php echo "<option value='". $row['id'] ."'>". $row['title'] ."</option>" ?>

                           <?php } // endwhile; ?>

                       </select>
                   </p>
                   <p>
                       <label>Status :</label> <select name="status" class="status" required>
                           <option value="1">Yes</option>
                           <option value="0">No</option>
                       </select>
                   </p>
                   <p>
                       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Activitie" class="submit">
                   </p>
               </form>

           </div>
           <!-- add-activitie-content end -->

           <div class="footer">
               <div class="main-footer">
           <?php include 'includes/admin-footer.php';?>
       </div>
           </div>
           <!-- footer end -->

       </div>
       <!-- wrapper end -->

   </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. This is my php processing page

   ```
   <?php

   include '../../functions/process-database.php';

   print_r($_POST);

   if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == "Add Activitie") {
       echo "works";

       $title = $_POST['title'];
       $description = $_POST['description'];
       $date = $_POST['date'];
       $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
       $status = $_POST['status'];

       if (! empty ( $_FILES )) {
           $image = time () . "-" . basename ( $_FILES ['img'] ['name'] );
           move_uploaded_file ( $_FILES ['img'] ['tmp_name'], "../../images/activities/$image" );
       } else {
           echo "Error: No Image Selected"; exit ();
       }

       $query = "INSERT INTO `activitie`(`title`, `description`, `date`, `image`, `category_id`, `status`) VALUES  ('$title','$description','$date','$image','$category_id','$status')";
       $result = mysqli_query ( $conn, $query );

       print_r($_POST);exit;

       if ($result) {
           header('Location: ../display-activitie.php');
       } else {
           die ( mysqli_error () );
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change that:

```
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Activitie" class="submit">
```

to

```
 <input type = "hidden" name = "submit" value = "Add Activitie"/>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Add Activitie" class = "submit">
```